# Cleaner way to write this check?

Tags: php

I have the following two arrays (`var_dumped`):

```
array (size=3)
  'param' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'Example' (length=7)
  'page-template' => string 'general' (length=7)
  'action' => 
    object(Closure)[2125]

array (size=3)
  'param' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'Example' (length=7)
  'page-template' => string 'general' (length=7)
  'action' => 
    object(Closure)[2126]
```

Now they are the same, they even call the same function (in `'action'`) but I cannot do `===` on them because of the closure, so I wrote this check:

```
foreach(self::$registeredRoutes[$routeName] as $routeActions) {
    if (!is_callable($action) && !is_callable($routeActions)) {
        if (isset($routeActions['param']) && isset($action['param'])
            && $routeActions['param'] === $action['param'] &&
            isset($routeActions['page-template']) &&
            isset($action['page-template']) &&
            $routeActions['page-template'] === $action['page-template']
            ) {

            var_dump('hello');
        }
    }
}
```

Accept it makes me want to vomit because of the if statement. Is there a cleaner, testable way of writing this where I still get the same result?

Comment: This looks a question that you could post in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ :)

Comment: @AlvaroSantisteban I get flamed less here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now they are the same, they even call the same function

Apparently not.

```
$func = function() {
    // ...
};

$arr1 = array(
    'param' => array('Example'),
    'page-template' => 'general',
    'action' => $func);

$arr2 = array(
    'param' => array('Example'),
    'page-template' => 'general',
    'action' => $func);

var_dump($arr1 === $arr2); // true
```

You can also simply don't use anonymous functions.

Comment: its not `$func == function(){}` its just `function(){}` that's passed in. thats why the action is different.